# Rename archive when storing to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, opentok, tokbox

I have configured OpenTok to use my own S3 bucket to store recorded video. Videos in my S3 bucket are named

`<ProjectApiKey>/<ArchiveId>/archive.mp4`

I would like to have the name of the file contain some other attributes so that I can group them by specific clients and/or users. for example,

`<ProjectApiKey>/<ClientId>/<UserId>/<ArchiveId>/<Filename>.mp4`

(ClientId and UserId are values that are controlled by my application)

Is there a way to achieve such a naming schema when the archive file is written to my S3 bucket?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenTok QA staff here,

No, that is not something you can do. What you can use is the *name* attribute when creating the archive. Then, if you need to download the archive, you can use this value to name the final file.

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/archiving/